# Selecting previous target in a second command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a system that prevents players from using certain items.

In one command block, I have the following command `clear @a diamond_sword` executing constantly through a clock.

Off the side of that command block I have a red stone comparator to catch the output and emit a signal if the command is executed successfully (It managed to clear a Diamond Sword from a player's inventory).

That comparator is supposed to trigger another command block who uses `/tell` to send a message to that player who had his Diamond Sword removed a message like:
 ***"You are not allowed to use Diamond Swords."***

What command can I use in the second command block to send that message only to the players who have Diamond Swords cleared off their inventory?

`/tell @p ...` doesn't work, as it merely selects the nearest player. 
`/tell @r ...` will target a random player, and 
`/tell @a ...` will message everyone.

How can I make it target the last target of the previous command block (The one with the `/clear` command)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to do this with scoreboards.  My solution won't prevent getting diamond swords, but it will prevent crafting them and using them, i.e. a player can have a diamond sword in their inventory, as long as they never use it.  How it gets there without crafting it, though, is pretty much impossible without cheats.

First, you need to set up 2 scoreboard objectives, one for crafting, and one for using:

```
/scoreboard objectives add craftedDiamondSword stat.craftItem.276
/scoreboard objectives add usedDiamondSword stat.useItem.276
```

Next, you need to set up two nearly identical chains of command blocks, one for each scoreboard objective.  This will run on a clock like you already have.  I'll only give the commands for using, so just replace that in the second chain with the crafting objective.

First, clear those players inventories:

```
clear @a[score_usedDiamondSword_min=1] 276
```

Next, tell the players that used a diamond sword to not use it, and reset their score:

```
tell @a[score_usedDiamondSword_min=1] Don't use diamond swords!
scoreboard players set @a[score_usedDiamondSword_min=1] usedDiamondSword 0
```

This last command block doesn't really need the `[score_usedDiamondSword_min=1]` but it's useful.

I got this to work in a single line of command blocks with redstone over top for the uses chain, but it wouldn't work for the crafting.  The solution is to pipe the result from the clear command block into the tell and set scoreboard command blocks with comparators.  Here's a pic of the two setups:

[image: Diamond Sword clearer]

Use whatever clock you want.

Additionally, if you never, ever want players to have a diamond sword, even in their inventory, and even if they don't use it, you can still clear from `@a`, and then just `say` to not use diamond swords if one is found.

---

### Update for added 1.8 functionality:

The 1.8 snapshots have added the option to match players against the `Inventory` NBT tag when setting or incrementing a scoreboard objective.  This means we can set up a dummy scoreboard objective to track whenever someone has a Diamond Sword in their inventory, regardless if they've used it or crafted it.  First, set up the scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add hasDiamondSword dummy
```

Next, we need to run two command blocks on the same clock; one to set players scores, and another to check those player's scores and clear the diamond swords:

```
scoreboard players add @a hasDiamondSword 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}]}
clear @a[score_hasDiamondSword_min=1] minecraft:diamond_sword
```

The second command is fairly similar to the old commands, except instead of using the old ID number, I'm using the name instead.  The first is a bit more complicated, so let's walk through it.  Basically it says add to all players on their `hasDiamondSword` objective the value 1 *if* that player has an inventory and that inventory contains a diamond sword.  So, for anyone that has a diamond sword in their inventory, their `hasDiamondSword` objective will be incremented.

Finally, like in the old version, we need to `tell` the players to not use diamond swords, and to reset their `hasDiamondSword` objective:

```
tell @a[score_hasDiamondSword_min=1] Don't use diamond swords!
scoreboard players set @a[score_hasDiamondSword_min=1] hasDiamondSword 0
```

I stacked these two command blocks (with the `tell` on bottom) and fed them with a comparator from the `clear` command block.  This is what it all looks like in the end:

[image: command block setup]

Comment: Hold on, why is it necessary to check whether the player has the sword instead of just doing `/clear @a minecraft:diamond_sword`?

Comment: Because the OP wanted to `tell` the offender not to use a diamond sword. You can do that now without the scoreboard, but not when this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but seems to me that you could notify all players with a diamond sword first, THEN remove all diamond swords. I haven't tested it but

```
tell @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}]} Don't use diamond swords!
```

and only then

```
clear @a diamond_sword
```