# Is it possible to check for an injured player in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a mini-game in Minecraft, where I must check to see if the player is injured. The injured player will then be given an item. My guess is that the command would look something like `/testfor @p[injured=true]`, but this command doesn't work. Is there a command for this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/138526/1351

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no direct command in Minecraft for injured. However you can use a scoreboard to track if the player has taken damage. You can start by adding a scoreboard objective with the following command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Health health
```

You are then able to detect (/testfor) if someone is not at 20 health using a command block or though the scoreboard.

Learn more on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tech No problem if you need any help with the command you know where to find me.