# how to not commence a command depending on player health?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command that simply turns grass into dirt when a player stands on it.

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt
```

Is there any way to make this not happen when the player's health is full?
(It may not involve any comparators, only command blocks as I am using a single command block generator, therefore it will come with a constant clock as well.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check for an injured player in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145030/is-it-possible-to-check-for-an-injured-player-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 5):

**First**, make a scoreboard objective that tracks the player's health:

Create the objective (run only **once**):

```
/scoreboard objectives add Health health
```

**Then** you run the `execute` command as following:

```
/execute @a[score_Health_min=0,score_Health=19] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt
```

How this works is that it runs the command for all players with a maximum `Health` score of `19`.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute positioned as @a[scores={Health=0..19}] if block ~ ~-1 ~ grass run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt`