# How to detect when the player is at half a heart with command blocks 1.16.3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a game where if the player is at half a heart I want to teleport them to a place. Is it possible to detect player health with command blocks? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check for an injured player in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145030/is-it-possible-to-check-for-an-injured-player-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this method you need a scoreboard for health. You can make it with the following command.

```
scoreboard objectives add health health
```

To test if a player has a certain amount of health, you can do it with the following command:

```
execute as @a[scores={health=<number>}] at @s run tp <coordinates>
```

Default health is 0–20. Half a heart is 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!