# How to make a spot to enter codes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to make a Minecraft minigame map where you can enter a code to get something. Here is how I would like it to work.

When you first join you get a written book inside it says:

> Instructions:
>   Bla bla bla
>   Click "here" if you have a code.

Then if you click "here" it gives you a book and quill that says:

> Enter code below:
>   Code:

Then they type a code, sign, close it and title it "code".  Then takes it and gives them a reward or something.

Comment: Just wondering would you be hosting this on a bukkit server (so that plugins would be a option) or is this a vanilla map you would distribute?

Comment: The easiest way that I can think of is not to use a book, but rather a nametag and something that can be named, say a wooden sword.  You can detect the name of something easily enough, so you just need to provide the item, an anvil, and the necessary experience (all easily accomplished as well). I don't have the time currently to flesh out the answer, but it'll look something like [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/138526/1351) I gave a while ago.

Comment: And actually, come to think of it, you don't even need the nametag.

Comment: @sebie its for a sigle player world that people might be able to download.

Comment: Is Computercraft an option?

Comment: http://minecraftjson.com/ is tool for generating JSON formatted NBT. You may need to use NBT editing tool for entering newline character for Book and Quill.

Comment: Vanilla minecraft

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two methods that come to mind:

#### Book and Quill

If you want to use the book and quill, you could detect what metadata the book had in it by using this command:

```
/testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:writable_book,tag:{pages:["CODE"]}}}
```

You can replace @p by whatever Target Selector (+Arguments) you like, but note the space after @p. This also works for written books with a specific title.

```
 /testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:written_book,tag:{title:"TITLE",pages:["CODE"]}}}
```

Check the wiki page for [item NBT structure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_Format#Item_structure).

#### Item Name

As has been suggested, you could test for the name of an item (like in the map The Code by JesperTheEnd).

```
/clear @p paper 0 0 {display:{Name:"CODE"}}
```

Comment: Great first answer ZL123. I took the liberty of expanding it slightly to include checking for Written Books with a specific title.